# Web scraping request stopped working, showing "Response [401]" in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=ACCEQN'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
print(data)

prices = data['grapthData']
print(prices)
```

It was working fine but now it showing error "Response [401]"

Comment: This page couldn't be visited now.

Comment: Can you please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: If you visit it in browser, you couldn't get the info you want.I have no idea, you need to find another way.

Comment: Can you post URL that I can view in the browser from where you want to get the data (not the Json link you have in the question) ?

Comment: Sir url is same, https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=ACCEQN

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's all about the site's authentication requirements. It requires a certain level of authorization to access like this.

Comment: Sir, Can you please suggest a solution for it, I tried all things like- set requests header, Cookies, etc but still not able to access the data.